# CSV file has dates formatted e.g 20140530 that are not recognised as dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, format

CSV file has dates formatted e.g 20140530 ( should be 30/05/2014) that are not recognised as dates.

Is there a quick fix to convert them to a date format without retyping whole column?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm thinking bash, specifically awk &/or date could tear through megs of csv file(s) in a few seconds converting date formats...

Answer (score 1):

you can use a calculated column which quickly do it for you:

`=DATE(LEFT(A2,4),MID(A2,5,2),RIGHT(A2,2)`

supposing that original data is in Column A

Answer (score 0):

Select the cell(s)

Select the `Text to columns` wizard from the `Data Tools` tab on the `Data` Ribbon

`Next` at steps 1 and 2

At step 3 select `Date: YMD`

`Finish`